# best way to get business unit wise subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

Please suggest if there is any way to get subscribers list business unit wise without actually going to each BU as we have over 50 BU.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribers actually live at the parent business unit level, for all child BUs. From the Parent Business Unit, you can apply 'Business Unit Filters' to segment the All Subscriber list so a subset of subscribers may appear in the child BU level.

If you are wanting to build a list of subscribers per BU, then you could select from _Subscribers and replicate the same BU Filter criteria to build you counts for each child BU

Comment: How would you apply the business unit filter to the _Subscribers system data view?

Comment: Go to Admin > Business Units and select (tick) and business unit and click 'Define Business Unit Filter' where you will then see what filters are being applied for the same BU. Take note of the logic - it will work from Profile Attributed of your system. From there, you will built a SQL to select from _Subscriberd and hopefully be able to apply the same selection criteria